# Ruby #match? misses trailing white space

Tags: ruby, string, comparison, match

`match?` in Ruby seems to miss the trailing white space at the end of a string.

```
b = "hello world" # no white space
c = "hello world " # trailing white space

c.match?(b)
=> true # misses the white space, only looks at the word characters

b.match?(c)
=> false # detects the white space
```

The neatest solution I can think of is this:

```
b.match?(c) && c.match?(b)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You seem to miss what `match?` is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if two strings are equal use:

```
b.eql?(c) #=> false
c.eql?(b) #=> false
```

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-eql-3F):

> `eql?(other) → true or false`
>
> Two strings are equal if they have the same length and content.

Whereas [`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) matches pattern by converting the argument into a regexp. And of cause the pattern `/hello world/` can found in the string `"hello world "` but not vice versa.

Comment: `eql?`? Seriously? :)

Comment: Similarity you could call [`==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) with the difference that if the object is not an instance of *String* `to_str` will be called if that object responds to it before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Match is a condition of something matching and similar but it doesn't look for exact or same. So, its better is use
equal method

```
class RubyMatch
def self.rubyMatch
b='hello world'
c='hello world '
puts b.equal?(c) #1
puts c.equal?(b) #2
end
end

RubyMatch.rubyMatch
```

Output

```
false
false
```

So you can use only one check  #1 or #2

Comment: Keep in mind that [*BasicObject#equal?*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-equal-3F) uses object id comparison. Not content comparison. Making `'foo'.equal?('foo') #=> false` since it's not the same object, but rather 2 different objects with the same content.